# How to store organization data (domain of organization data): each in separate instance or in one common?

Tags: .net, database, oracle, database-design, saas

Out company wants to start new SaaS project. The purpose of project is to manage organization resources in warehouses. As in other regular SaaS system customer should has ability to register his company (create account for it) and start using system right now.

Approximate features:

1. Add item to warehouse
2. Change item in warehouse
3. Delete item in warehouse
4. Add new category of items
5. Change categories
6. Delete categories
7. Add new warehouse (one organization may has many warehouses) etc.

It assumed to be a big volume of data will be storing in DB. RDMBS is Oracle.

One team memeber suggest to use separate DB instance for each registered client. He thinks this way will help escape from situations then one huge registered client (ogranization that uses this SaaS system) will make huge load on database, disturbing other (small) clients.

Also, in future, we plan to has ability to move data of big customer, by request, to its dedicated server, located in its own datacenter.

In my opinion, use separate instance for each client is wrong and redundant.

So, how can I limit customer in using server's resources to some quota?

Technologies we use: .net 4 (C#), Oracle, Windows servers.

Hope for your help and advices! 
Very appreciate it!

---

**EDIT**

As question was marked as "too broad" here my clarifications:

1. The main issue of question is how can we organize resource usage quota for different users when there is only one (basic) connection to DB?
2. How can we easily migrate data of customer (portion of tables data what related to him) to another server by his request?

Comment: Could somebody review answer and decide is it really "too broad" now?

Answer (score 2):

Using multiple instances is not an efficient use of hardware and will increase the administrative overhead.  This is true even if your colleague is envisaging using VMs on big iron.

A better solution would be to have a single instance and use Resource Management to set the limits of consumption.  Oracle's Resource Manager allows us to come up with some pretty sophisticated allocation plans.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dbrm001.htm#ADMIN11851).